# Mongodb is not starting when using AWS S3 bucket as a mongodb data path

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to start the MongoDB service after giving the data path to the AWS s3 bucket.

But I'm facing issue like :

> ● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server    Loaded: loaded
> (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-12-24 13:12:21 IST;
> 5min ago
> Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual   Process: 28668 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited,
> status=1/FAILURE)  Main PID: 28668 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.  mongod[28668]:
> {"t":{"$date":"2020-12-24T07:42:21.189Z"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",
> "id":20574,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Error during global initi
> systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited,
> status=1/FAILURE  systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result
> 'exit-code'. ...skipping...

And when I'm giving the data path to the Server location the MongoDB is working perfectly.

Can anyone please help me to resolve this error?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Status=1 usually indicates failure to open the log file for writing.

Make sure the log path in the configuration is valid, and the user running mongod has permission to create files there.